# Erro na multiplicação e divisão (java)

Tags: java, interface

Estou com problemas pra implementar multiplicação e divisão 
na minha calculadora com interface gráfica.

Independente de qualquer coisa que eu colocar usando qualquer um dos 
operadores (/ e *), o resultado de saída é 0.

Soma e subtração estão funcionando normalmente.

---

```
package pkgCalculadora;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JButton butSomar,butSubtrair, butMultiplicar, butDividir, butIgual;
private JButton but0,but1,but2,but3,but4,but5,but6,but7,but8,but9;
private JTextField campo1;
private JPanel painel1 = new JPanel();
private JPanel painel2 = new JPanel();
private JPanel painel3 = new JPanel();
private int leitura;
private int memoria;
private int op;

public Calculadora()
{
    super("Calculadora");        

    butSomar  = new JButton("+");     
    butSubtrair = new JButton(" -");
    butMultiplicar = new JButton("*");
    butDividir = new JButton(" /");
    butIgual = new JButton("=");

    but0 = new JButton("0");
    but1 = new JButton("1");
    but2 = new JButton("2");
    but3 = new JButton("3");
    but4 = new JButton("4");
    but5 = new JButton("5");
    but6 = new JButton("6");
    but7 = new JButton("7");
    but8 = new JButton("8");
    but9 = new JButton("9");

    campo1 = new JTextField(15);

    painel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    painel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(painel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    painel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    painel1.add(campo1);

    painel2.add(butSomar);
    painel2.add(butSubtrair);
    painel2.add(butMultiplicar);
    painel2.add(butDividir);
    painel2.add(butIgual);

    painel3.add(but0);
    painel3.add(but1);
    painel3.add(but2);
    painel3.add(but3);
    painel3.add(but4);
    painel3.add(but5);
    painel3.add(but6);
    painel3.add(but7);
    painel3.add(but8);
    painel3.add(but9);
    painel3.add(but0);

    butSomar.addActionListener(this);
    butSubtrair.addActionListener(this);
    butMultiplicar.addActionListener(this);
    butDividir.addActionListener(this);
    butIgual.addActionListener(this);

    but0.addActionListener(this);
    but1.addActionListener(this);
    but2.addActionListener(this);
    but3.addActionListener(this);
    but4.addActionListener(this);
    but5.addActionListener(this);
    but6.addActionListener(this);
    but7.addActionListener(this);
    but8.addActionListener(this);
    but9.addActionListener(this);


    add(painel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(painel2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(painel3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 // certo

    // <HARD 1>

butSomar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "+");
    }
});

butSubtrair.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "-");
    }
});

butMultiplicar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "*");
    }
});

butDividir.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "/");
    }
});

but1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){   
    leitura += 1;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "1");
    }
});

but2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){   
    leitura += 2;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "2");
    }
});

but3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
    leitura += 3;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "3");
    }
});

but4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
    leitura += 4;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "4");
    }
});

but5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    leitura += 5;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "5");
    }
});

but6.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    leitura += 6;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "6");
    }
});

but7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    leitura += 7;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "7");
    }
});

but8.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    leitura += 8;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "8");
    }
});

but9.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    leitura += 9;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "9");
    }
});

but0.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    leitura += 0;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "0");
    }
});

// </HARD 1>

// <HARD 2>

butSomar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        op = '+';
        memoria += leitura; // guarda leitura na memoria
        leitura = 0;        // reseta memoria

    }
});

butSubtrair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        op = '-';
        memoria -= leitura; 
        leitura = 0;        

    }
});

butMultiplicar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        op = '*';
        memoria *= leitura; 
        leitura = 0;        

    }
});

butDividir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        op = '/';
        memoria /= leitura; 
        leitura = 0;        

    }
});

butIgual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (op) {
            case '+': {
                memoria += leitura;
                break;
            }
            case '-': {
                memoria -= leitura;
                break;
            }
            case '*': {
                memoria *= leitura;
                break;
            }
            case '/': {
                memoria /= leitura;
                break;
            }
        }
        leitura = 0;
        campo1.setText("" + memoria);
    }
});

// </HARD 2>
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: Na multiplicação isto está acontecendo pelo fato de você atribuir 0 para leitura e após isso multiplicá-lo com memória. Porém não consegui identificar por que isso acontece para a divisão.

Comment: mas leitura naturalmente recebe 0, pois o valor dela é passado pra variavel 'memoria' .-.

Comment: Porque você usa `int` ao invés de `double`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu problema é que você nunca está atribuindo `memoria` explicitamente, somente através de operações com `leitura`. Na soma isso não é problema, pois:

1. Você digita `2`, o código faz `leitura = 2`; `memoria` é zero;
2. Você digita `+`, o código faz `memoria += leitura`; `memoria` agora é `2`;
3. Você digita `2`, o código faz `leitura = 2`; `memoria` é `2`;
4. Você digita `=`, o código faz `memoria += leitura`; `memoria` agora é `4`.

Nas demais, deveria ser (você mencionou que a subtração funciona, mas de acordo com seu código não deveria funcionar...). Por exemplo, na divisão:

1. Você digita `2`, o código faz `leitura = 2`; `memoria` é zero;
2. Você digita `/`, o código faz `memoria /= leitura`; `memoria` ainda é zero;
3. Você digita `2`, o código faz `leitura = 2`; `memoria` é zero;
4. Você digita `=`, o código faz `memoria /= leitura`; `memoria` continua zero.

O que você precisaria fazer, em qualquer uma das quatro operações, seria algo como:

```
butMultiplicar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        op = '*';
        memoria = leitura; // Apenas atribua a "memoria" o valor de "leitura"
        leitura = 0;        
    }
});
```

Mas... isso nos leva a um segundo problema no seu código: cada vez que você entra com um dígito, o valor do campo de texto está sendo atualizado corretamente, mas o valor de `leitura` não:

1. `leitura` é zero;
2. Você digita `2`, o código faz `leitura += 2`; `leitura` agora é `2`;
3. Você digita `2`, o código faz `leitura += 2`; `leitura` agora é `4`!

Se você pretende usar operandos com mais de um dígito, é preciso multiplicar o valor atual por `10` antes de somar o dígito seguinte:

```
but2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){   
    leitura = leitura*10 + 2;
    campo1.setText(campo1.getText() + "2");
    }
});
```

Por último, uma pergunta: e se você entrar com `2*2*2=`? Somente com as alterações acima, não seria suficiente, pois a segunda entrada de `*` iria sobrescrever `memoria` com `2` e o primeiro `2*` seria perdido. A solução é verificar - antes de atribuir um operador - se já tinha outro operador atribuído ali ou não. Se não tiver, sobrescreva `memoria`; caso contrário, *faça a operação* entre `leitura`, `op` e `memoria`:

```
private void calcular() {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            memoria + leitura;
            break;
        case '-':
            memoria -= leitura;
            break;
        case '*':
            memoria *= leitura;
            break;
        case '/':
            memoria /= leitura;
            break;
        case 0:
            memoria = leitura; // Nenhuma operação anterior, só atribua
    }
}

butMultiplicar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        calcular();  // Atualiza memoria,
        op = '*';    // Coloca o novo operador
        leitura = 0; // E limpa leitura
    }
});
```

Além dos quatro operadores, o botão de igual também pode usar essa função `calcular`, em vez de repetir a lógica:

```
butIgual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        calcular();                   // Atualiza "memoria"
        campo1.setText("" + memoria); // Exibe seu valor
        leitura = memoria = op = 0;   // Limpa todos os dados
    }
});
```

Comment: Sua explicação foi perfeita, me ajudou até em erros que eu não havia visto. Obrigado.